# Query becomes slow when rows growing over 1 million

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
PERSON (
  id,
  number
)
client
(
    ID                         bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    PERSON_ID               bigint              not null,
    NUMBER_TYPE             varchar(80)         null,
    NUMBER             varchar(80)              not null,
    ENTITY_ID                  bigint              null,
    ENTITY_TYPE                varchar(80)         not null,
    STATUS                     varchar(20)         not null,
    START_DATE                 datetime            null,
    END_DATE                   datetime            null,
    TENANT_ID                    bigint          null
  
    constraint FK_C_P
        foreign key (PERSON_ID) references person (ID),
)
    charset = utf8;

create index IDX_NUMBER_TYPE
    on client (NUMBER_TYPE);


create index IDX_TENANT_NUMBER_TYPE_START_DATE
    on client (TENANT_ID, NUMBER_TYPE, START_DATE);

create index IDX_TENANT_STATUS_START_DATE
    on client (TENANT_ID, STATUS, START_DATE);
create index idx_or_p_entity
on client (PERSON_ID, ENTITY_ID, ENTITY_TYPE);
```

I have a procedure which copying data from one to another table, here is the main query which becomes slow when rows grow over 1 million:

```
START TRANSACTION
    UPDATE client target, (SELECT p.number_type as person_number_type, p.id as person_id
                           FROM person p JOIN client c ON c.person_id = p.id
                           WHERE p.number_type is null limit 10000)
    SET target.number_type = person_number_type WHERE target.person_id = person_id;
    COMMIT;
    select sleep(.01)
    set i = i-1;
   i =0 end repeat;
```

```
Expain:
+--+-----------+----------+------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------+--------------------+-----+-----------+
|id|select_type|table     |type  |possible_keys                                   |key                                   |key_len|ref                 |rows |Extra      |
+--+-----------+----------+------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------+--------------------+-----+-----------+
|1 |PRIMARY    |<derived2>|ALL   |NULL                                            |NULL                                  |NULL   |NULL                |10000|           |
|1 |PRIMARY    |target    |eq_ref|PRIMARY                                         |PRIMARY                               |8      |affected_op.person_id|1    |           |
|2 |DERIVED    |p         |index |PRIMARY                                         |IDX_PERSON_TENANT_ID_NUMBER_TYPE     |161    |NULL                |35858|Using index|
|2 |DERIVED    |c         |ref   |FK_C_P,idx_or_p_entity,IDX_NUMBER_TYPE|idx_or_p_entity                              |8      |db.p.ID          |153  |Using where|
+--+-----------+----------+------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------+--------------------+-----+-----------+


SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM client = 9 850 227
SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM person = 36 067
```

// In 1 hour was updated 571 000 rows

It runs pretty fast for an environment with rows of around 1 million. When rows grow, it becomes super bad.
Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: Whenever you ask about SQL query optimization, **show the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: Sorry guys for the bad clarifications... I am using MariaDB @HoneyBadger

Comment: @AndyLester tried to add more information. Sorry for the bad clarifications. Hope it helps